# How do you solve trig integrals using recursions?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

My calculus professor gave us the problem $\int \sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)dx$ and told us to solve it via recursion but I can't seem to find how to do it in my textbook.

Comment: Try using the substitution $\sin^2x \cos^2x = \sin^2(2x)/4$.

Comment: I know how to solve it that way, but the teacher said specifically to use recursion in the problem. Maybe I'm not understanding it correctly?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae) for a general discussion how integrals are solved using reduction formulae (which, in a way, is recursion, as you have termed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's we evaluate
\begin{equation}
I_n=\int\sin^n ax\ dx
\end{equation}
Rewrite as
\begin{equation}
I_n=\int\sin^{n-1} ax\sin ax\ dx=-\frac{1}{a}\int\sin^{n-1} ax\ d(\cos ax)
\end{equation}
Now integrating by parts
\begin{align}
I_n&=-\frac{\sin^{n-1} ax\cos ax}{a}+(n-1)\int\cos^2ax\sin^{n-2} ax\ dx\\[10pt]
&=-\frac{\sin^{n-1} ax\cos ax}{a}+(n-1)\int(1-\sin^2ax)\sin^{n-2} ax\ dx\\[10pt]
&=-\frac{\sin^{n-1} ax\cos ax}{a}+(n-1)\int\sin^{n-2} ax\ dx-(n-1)\int\sin^n ax\ dx\\[10pt]
&=-\frac{\sin^{n-1} ax\cos ax}{a}+(n-1)I_{n-2}-(n-1)I_{n}\\[10pt]
&=\frac{a(n-1)I_{n-2}-\sin^{n-1}ax\cos ax}{an}
\end{align}
In your case, we have
\begin{equation}
\int\sin^2x\cos^2x\ dx=\frac{1}{4}\int\sin^22x\ dx
\end{equation}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: very creative your answer, impressive

Answer (score 1):

$$I = \int \sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)dx$$

$$I = \int \frac{1}{4}sin^2 2xdx$$

$$I = \int \frac{1}{8}(1-cos 4x)dx$$

$$I = \frac{1}{8}x - \frac{1}{32}sin 4x$$

Comment: I know how to solve it that way, but the teacher said specifically to use recursion in the problem. Maybe I'm not understanding it correctly?

Comment: Recursion will come if you have sin^2(x)cos(x) as the integrand I think.  In the present form, I doubt there will any recursion.  Have you copied the integrand correctly

Comment: i think i did, this is her answer to how to solve the problem: https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/davis/408d/extra/e12013soln.pdf (page 4 question 2)

Comment: You missed a square in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)dx$$

To solve this integral, I would use the trig identities:

$$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$$
$$\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$$

Comment: I know how to solve it that way, but the teacher said specifically to use recursion in the problem. Maybe I'm not understanding it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\sin^{2}(x)\cos^{2}(x)  dx$$
we have:
$$\frac{1}{4}\sin^{2}(2x)=\sin^{2}(x)\cos^{2}(x) $$
and then:
$$\frac{1}{4}\sin^{2}(2x)=\frac{1-\cos(4x)}{8}$$
finally:
$$\int\frac{1-\cos(4x)}{8}dx=\frac{x}{8}-\frac{\sin(4x)}{32}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin ^2 x \cos^2 x= sin ^2 (2x) / 4 = \frac14 \cdot \frac12 (1-\cos (4x))=\frac18 (1-\cos (4x))$$

$$\int \sin ^2 x \cos^2 x dx = \int \frac18 (1-\cos (4x)) dx = \frac18 x- \frac1{32} \sin (4x) +C$$